# C# tuple array throws out of memory excpetion

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

Just wanted to know why this line throws an excpetion on runtime but compiles fine.

Also what is the best way to prevent this?

```
var vowelsArray = new char['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'] ; // Is of type char[,,,,]
```

and this one works since it's a normal char array

```
var vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' }; // Is of type char[]?
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/pulJI4

In the output window you'll see the OutOfMemory Exception

Comment: a char can be implicitly converted to a `short`, so the first can be trated as if you would initialize a jagged array with 5 dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone wondering: Like @MongZhu said, it is a jagged Array.
So, when we have

```cs
int[] array1 = new int[5];
```

```
00
00
00
00
00
```

it creates an array within an array at the first dimension with 5 entries.

But as soon as we add, another dimension i.e

```cs
int[,] array1 = new int[5,2];
```

```
    0   1
0   00  00
1   00  00
2   00  00
3   00  00
4   00  00
```

The size of the array is suddenly doubled.

The array size is multiplied by the result of the previous indexies.
Meaning that if we were to have an array with [5,2,3] we would get 5 * 2 * 3 = 30

---

To answer my own question, why the jagged array caused an exception:

The array size increased since the char gets converted into an number to get a size out of it. Here the letter 'a' represents the number 97, therefor all the vowels respond to numbers that multiply each other. Which are:

```
a   97  
i   105 
e   101 
o   111
u   117
```

This leads to an array with entries: 13’359’532’095 (more than 13 **billion** characters). And since .Net uses the full Unicode 4-byte encoding for characters, it **works out as an attempt to allocate nearly 50 GB of RAM.**